# How to run a javascript function when a page dynamically loads content

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I am currently writing some Javascript code that adds some tags across text in an HTML file after the page loads. I use the

```
window.onload
```

method for achieving this.

However, I am facing an issue in pages like google plus, where you get more content as you scroll down. Is there a way of calling my JS function when such a page adds more content?

Thanks

Akshay

Comment: See [DOM Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events#DOM_mutation_events).

Comment: Can you use jQuery? or just need to use plain javascript.  If you can use jQuery, try using selector's "on" for lazy binding.

Comment: My bad! Use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways how to get this working. You can either use jquery like this:

```
$('#mydiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    // your code goes here
    alert('changed');
});
```

Note that this is not supported in IE8( and below).

Or you can run loop and continuously fire the desired code:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // your code goes here
}, 1000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8RF5r/5/

Comment: I tried using the first one, but I am getting the following error:

rror: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","body"]]]>


I am using tampermonkey in chrome for testing, and just pasted your code there and changed the 'mydiv' to 'body'

Comment: I have tried it and it works as expected, I just have a typo in my definition that I have forgotten to add "#" in my selector. Now I have also added working fiddle.

Comment: Hi @Matúš Dúbrava. This works :) However, I noticed that it gives a callback on any and every change when I do it for the page body. Is there a way to do this after the HTML of a page becomes 'stable'/ I guess one way to do this would be with a timeout that fires if no change has happened for some preset time. Are there any other, less heuristic methods you can think of?

Comment: What you are asking for is algorithmically impossible because there is no such thing as 'stable' state. Your page has no idea whether it content can be changed again or this was the last change and there will be no more changes. Therefore you can either fire the timeout after certain amount of time as you said or specify maximum number of changes, increase counter with every change and when the maximum is reached you know that that is your desired event. Other than that you have no other options.

Comment: True. I realized that soon.. I just went ahead with the second method: interval based updates. I tried the MutationObservers method, but apparently that is not supported in Android 4.2, Thanks for the help and the explanation